# How to set default value and also use Environment variable in application.conf

Tags: scala, playframework, config

I want to set value for one of config variable in application.conf using environment variable. But if this env variable is not present I want to default config to a certain value instead of erring out. 
Is this possible? Here is setting for reference.

```
test.myframework {
host = ${TEST_HOST_NAME}
}
```

Here if TEST_HOST_NAME if not present can I default host to localhost?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is described in the play documentation [Production Configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ProductionConfiguration#Using-environment-variables):

```
my.key = defaultvalue
my.key = ${?MY_KEY_ENV}
```